# ReactJS encounter with "Target container is not a DOM element", tried a lot solution but not worked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm doing a simple react app, I want to write a function to loop through my array using map() and display them on the page, but I encountered with a problem says "target container is not a DOM element", I've tried a lot solutions online but none of them worked for me, is there anyone can help me, thank you.

This is the first file, and this displays each element.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';

   import Header from './components/Header.js';
   import Summary from './components/Summary.js';
   import Education from './components/Education.js';
   import Project from './components/Project.js';
   import Experience from './components/Experience.js';

   class App extends Component {
     render() {
      return (
        <body className="App">
         <Header />
          <Summary />
           <Education />
            <Experience />
             <Project />
        </body>
        );
     }
   }

   export default App;
```

This is the second file, and this is for Project display.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Project(props) {
  const content = props.projects.map((project) =>
    <div key={project.id}>
      <h3 className="ProjectTitle">{project.title}</h3>
      <p className="ProjectDetail">{project.detail}</p>
    </div>
  );

  return(
    <div>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

const projects = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Consumer Electronics Retailer Web Application',
    detail: 'Consumer Electronics Retailer Web Application1',
    detail: 'Consumer Electronics Retailer Web Application2',
    detail: 'Consumer Electronics Retailer Web Application3'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Hotel Reservation Web Application',
    detail: 'Hotel Reservation Web Application1',
    detail: 'Hotel Reservation Web Application2',
    detail: 'Hotel Reservation Web Application3'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Android Library Management Application',
    detail: 'Android Library Management Application1',
    detail: 'Android Library Management Application2',
    detail: 'Android Library Management Application3'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Project projects={projects} />,
    document.getElementById('Project')
);

export default Project;
```

Comment: where is your DOMElement w/ the id of Project?

Answer (score 1):

It’s critical you import your *app* script after any DOM elements in your page that you intend to reference.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Project projects={projects} />, document.getElementById('Project'));
```

In this case you need to ensure that there is a DOM element with `id="Project"`, and your project script is added in the document body (after that element) to be able to reference to that particular element.

```
<body>
<div id="Project"></div>
<script src="/bundles-here.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Check the `index.html` you are seeing in your browser and search inside the body for an empty `div` element with an `id` (probably you will find `id="root"`.) Then use that id attribute in your `render`.

I also notice your `<App/>` component is rendering a `<body>` tag.
I think you should change that for a `<div>`.
And because the `App` component includes your `Project` component, it makes sense to update your `react-dom` render call to:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This time you are rendering all your components, including `<Project>`.

You can also check this [react-seed](https://github.com/uruit/react-seed) and [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) projects with code samples and a working[webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4) config for [react](/questions/tagged/react) apps

Comment: I kind of understand that, but I'm not sure how to modify the code, can you help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: what build tool are you using? webpack? or just an static `index.html`? - you need to update your html file.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm new to React, just installed the react following the official guide.

Comment: I created the app using npm command in command line, and was coding in the js file.

Comment: Ok. I do not use that starter project for my react app because I like to configure the project by myself. But probably if you don't change the id for the mount element it should work. I think these two simple projects can be helpful for you: [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) and [react-seed](https://github.com/UruIT/react-seed). You can find in those a working react app configured with webpack.